# How can I reorganize a dataframe with many groups?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very large transposed dataframe that I am trying to organize chronologically, by item. However, it is formatted very strangely and I am having trouble figuring out how to organize the frame as a whole. I can pick out one item at a time and doctor it, but that is not scalable.

Here is an example of the dataframe:

```
0         1       2     3     4     5
0      RowLabel ItemA ItemB ItemC ItemD...
2019   Oct      -22     12   15     0
2019   Nov      -4      -8   -4     12
2020   Jan       0      0    -3     5
...
```

What I have doctored for one item is what I would like to be repeated for all items, which would essentially be:

```
Year   Month   Qty   Item
2019   Oct     -22   ItemA
2019   Oct      12   ItemB
2019   Oct      15   ItemC
2019   Oct      0    ItemD
2019   Nov     -4    ItemA
2019   Nov     -8    ItemB
2019   Nov     -4    ItemC
2019   Nov     12    ItemD
...
```

Is there an easy way to do this that I'm missing?

Comment: What your are looking for is:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html

Comment: What are the column names in the original DataFrame? Just [0,1,2...]? IMO this looks more like a case for pandas.DataFrame.stack

Comment: @mcsoini yes, the transposed version I was given just names them 0,1,2... part of the reason I've been so confused

Comment: I am a bit unsure on how either of your solutions would be implemented; doesn't stack return 1-D arrays by index? And with pivot, how would I reference the items in the first row as something to filter by?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the clarifications in the OP comments, here is what I think you want to do:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
{0: [0, 2019, 2019, 2020],
 1: ['RowLabel', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Jan'],
 2: ['ItemA', -22, -4, 0],
 3: ['ItemB', 12, -8, 0],
 4: ['ItemC', 15, -4, -3],
 5: ['ItemD', 0, 12, 5]})

# get proper column names from the first table row
df.columns = df.iloc[0].replace({0: 'Year', 'RowLabel': 'Month'})
df.drop(index=0, inplace=True)

# set index; all columns which are not the index will be stacked
df.set_index(['Year', 'Month'], inplace=True)

# give the column levels proper names, which will become the stacked table columns
df.columns.name = 'Item'

# at this point, the table is ready for stacking: the remaining columns are 
# only the ItemX columns, all others are in the index
df.head(2)

Out[1]: 
Item       ItemA ItemB ItemC ItemD
Year Month                        
2019 Oct     -22    12    15     0
     Nov      -4    -8    -4    12

# stack
df = df.stack().rename('Qty').reset_index()

df.head()

Out[2]: 
   Year Month   Item  Qty
0  2019   Oct  ItemA  -22
1  2019   Oct  ItemB   12
2  2019   Oct  ItemC   15
3  2019   Oct  ItemD    0
4  2019   Nov  ItemA   -4
```